# How to change the name of a vim buffer

Tags: vim, buffer

Is it possible to change the name of a buffer in vim?

Specifically, I'm using [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) to open shells in vim (each shell is in a buffer) and with multiple shells, I see:

```
10: bash - 1
11: bash - 2
```

in my buffer list. I would like to rename these buffers with more meaningful names (e.g., "mercurial" instead of "bash - 2"). Is it possible?

Comment: Why  do you want to change name of buffer?@Barthelemy

Comment: The reason is stated in the question

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use `:file newname` to change the buffer name.

From [`:help :file_f`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Afile_f):

> Sets the current file name to `{name}`.  The optional ! avoids truncating the message, as with `:file`.
>   If the buffer did have a name, that name becomes the `alternate-file` name.  An unlisted buffer is created to hold the old name.

Comment: Thank you. But, to me, it was surprising because I could not find that command using various google searches.

Comment: its important to note that this basically changes the file's save path.  I was hoping for something like screen's naming of windows but it doesnt work like that

Comment: so this is renaming the file like `mv a b`

Comment: It may be better to do `:silent keepalt noautocmd file` instead to limit side effects. In the case of a buffer created with `:term` or `term_start()`, the original buffer name could be any string, but `:file name` forces the buffer name to be the name of a file, which is apparently given by `fnamemodify(name, ':p')`. The command also creates a swap file even if there was none before, but that can be suppressed with `:noswapfile`.

Answer (score 7):

If the buffer already has a filename, `:file` will not change the filename and will only change the alternate filename. You'll need to clear the name of the buffer with `:0f[ile]` to be able to put one.

```
:e foo

:0f
:file bar
```

Answer (score 4):

Rename the current buffer with [`:file <new-name>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:file_f) (or `:f <new-name>`):

> #### `:f[ile][!] {name}`
>
> Sets the current file name to `{name}`.  The optional `!` avoids truncating the message, as with [`:file`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:file).  If the buffer did have a name, that name becomes the [alternate-file](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#alternate-file) name.  An unlisted buffer is created to hold the old name.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do that from a vim function using a variable, you can do like that:

```
function! MyFunc()
  let file_name = 'Some data here'
  execute 'file ' . file_name
endfunction
```